# OpenTok users identification

Tags: javascript, webrtc, opentok

I am using OpenTok in Drupal 8. I want to allow users to connect to the session only one time with the publisher user role and the second time with a subscriber user role. I can`t do this on the server-side. Does OpenTok has this kind of functionality?

Answer (score 0):

Roles are defined in the [Token](https://tokbox.com/developer/guides/basics/#token). You mention you can't do this on the server-side (which is where tokens are generated,) so can you explain further how you're creating sessions/tokens? Example code and an explanation of your architecture (i.e. are you using 
[Embeds](https://tokbox.com/developer/embeds/), the OpenTok API or an SDK) would help as well.

Comment: I am using OpentTok Client SDK

Comment: I tried to solve this problem another way. I pass a unique user id and this way check if this user has another stream or does not.